# IF statement in Batch Script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I'm writing a batch script that switches between ip addresses depending on the users input.
The core functionality of the script works however I want to add some checks into each function to check which setting is already applied and give a response accordingly.

My current code is:

```
@ECHO OFF
::Change Static IP address for simulator or network connection

:MAINMENU choose option from menu
::Set Current IP Address

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IP | findstr 192."') do SET LOCAL_IP=%%i

ECHO.
ECHO. Set Workstation...........1
ECHO. Set Simulator.............2
ECHO. Quit (no further action)..Q
ECHO.
choice /c:Q21
ECHO.

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO WORK
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO SIM
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO EOF

::Change IP To network settings
:WORK
IF "LOCAL_IP"=="192.168.1.4" (
ECHO. You are already in this mode
GOTO MAINMENU 
) ELSE
(echo "Setting Static IP Information" 
netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=192.168.1.4 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.1.254 gwmetric=1 
netsh int ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=192.168.1.1

echo IP Address Set
goto MAINMENU)

::Set Simulator IP Address
:SIM
IF "LOCAL_IP"=="192.168.4.1" (
ECHO. You are already in this mode
GOTO MAINMENU
) ELSE
echo "Setting Static IP Information"
netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
netsh int ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=192.168.4.1 mask=255.255.255.0
echo "Setting Static IP Information"
goto MAINMENU

:EOF
pause
```

I'm having trouble getting the IF statement to compare the current IP address with the one i want to set it to.
Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong or offer some ideas to get this working please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `LOCAL_IP` is an environment variable, to use them you have to enclose the name within `%` so your code will be:

```
IF "%LOCAL_IP%"=="192.168.1.4" (
```

and

```
IF "%LOCAL_IP%"=="192.168.4.1" (
```

**Note:** where do you set that environment variable to actual value?

Comment: I set it everytime the menu is called as each function besides the one to terminate the script returns to the menu.
`for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IP | findstr 192."') do SET LOCAL_IP=%%i`

Comment: I've realised the code for getting the IP address was wrong.. I added `usebackq` before tokens=2 and the local_ip variable is now picking up an address...
a twist to the tale now and I get an invalid syntax error in the if statement now. I have also added the changes suggested by Adriano.

Comment: Post ur updated code, please! Tip: remove the **@echo off** to see what happens!

Comment: part 1
`::@ECHO OFF
::Change Static IP address for simulator or network connection

:MAINMENU choose option from menu
::Set Current IP Address

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"`) 

do Set LOCAL_IP=%%f

::Menu
ECHO.
ECHO. Set Workstation...........1
ECHO. Set Simulator.............2
ECHO. Quit (no further action)..Q
ECHO.
choice /c:Q21
ECHO.

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO WORK
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO SIM
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO EOF`

Comment: part 2
::Change IP To network settings
:WORK
IF "%LOCAL_IP%"=="192.168.1.4"
(ECHO. You are already in this mode && GOTO MAINMENU 
) ELSE
(echo "Setting Static IP Information" && netsh int ip set address name = "Local Area 

Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.1.4 mask = 255.255.255.0 gateway = 

192.168.1.254 gwmetric = 1 && netsh int ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" 

source = static addr = 192.168.1.1

echo IP Address Set
goto MAINMENU)

::Set Simulator IP Address
:SIM
IF "%LOCAL_IP%"=="192.168.4.1" (
ECHO. You are already in this mode
GOTO MAINMENU
) ELSE

Comment: part 3

(echo "Setting Static IP Information"
netsh int ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" source = dhcp
netsh int ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" source = dhcp
netsh int ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 

192.168.4.1 mask = 255.255.255.0
echo "Setting Static IP Information"
goto MAINMENU)

:EOF

I have no idea how to keep formatting with new lines so i apologise for the wall of text. If it's easier i can email or PM you the script.

Comment: :) Yes, it's pretty hard to read! Can't you edit your question to update the code? Otherwise send me by e-mail!

Comment: next question.. where do i get your email address from?! Cant see it on your profile

Comment: accepted Adriano's answer using %Local_IP% instead of Local_IP to compare variable value in the IF statement. Thank you very much!!